# One query, multiple date range

Tags: javascript, cube.js

I have a query like below :

```
 {
    "measures": [...],
    "dimensions": [],
     "timeDimensions": [
        {
            "dateRange": ["2020-01-03", "2020-31-03"]
        }
     ]
 }
```

it returns an array of ONE object  for example

```
[{ totalSales : 1234, totalDollar : "1234,56", ...}]
```

I woud like to compare thoses data with different period over time (client side). So my quesiton is : **Is it possible to get the result on multiple time range on single request**

for exemple

```
 {
    "measures": [...],
    "dimensions": [],
     "timeDimensions": [
        {
            "dateRange": ["2020-03-01", "{2020-03-31"]
        },
        {
            "dateRange": ["2020-02-01", "{2020-02-29"]
        }, 
        ...
     ]
 }
```

and have a result like

```
[
    { totalSales : 1234, totalDollar : "1234,56", ...},
    { totalSales : 2222, totalDollar : "232323,23", ...},
    ...
]
```

Is it possible to do that or i must execute several requests with different time range ?

Thanks

Comment: Whats your backend?

Comment: @GBWDev it's a cube.js query. https://cube.dev/

Comment: What happens when you try to run the example API call you wrote? docs say `timeDimensions` is an array of objects in timeDimension format - as opposed to a single object. Logic would suggest passing multiple is ok?

Comment: @GBWDev when multiples Objects are passed, it keep return an array wirth a single object. I think it take the intersection of the date ranges. But what i need is separated results for the same query but different time range. I don't even know if it's possible. Just asking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for now the simplest way to do it is to perform 2 separate queries. Please see https://github.com/cube-js/cube.js/issues/461

Answer (score 2):

In newer cube versions you can use `compareDateRange` instead of `dateRange` and pass it an array of dateRanges. See https://cube.dev/docs/query-format#time-dimensions-format